# Send and receive 3 elements of String buffer using socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am writing a program to send and recieve 3 charachters of string buffer. The following code prints the buffer using pointer. I want to add a feature of sending these elements 3 at a time, i.e. each time the 3 instructions starts with ff, using socket programming function send (This is a TCP connection,hence using send)

```
//Write a simple echo server

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

string buff1[]= {"0xff , 0xfd, 0x18,0xff,0xfd,0x23","0xff , 0xfd, 0x1e","0xff , 0xfd, 0x1d","0xff ,0xfd,0x17"};

int main()
{
  int sockfd , newsockfd , portno;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n;
  printf("\n=====================================================\nServer Side\n=====================================================\n");
  while(buff1[count].length()>0)
  {
    const unsigned char *ptr = (const unsigned char*)buff1[count].c_str();
    printf("Server Sending message %d of size:%d",count,buff1[count].length());
    for(int i = 0 ; i < buff1[count].length(); i++)
    {
         printf("%c",*ptr);
         ptr++;
    }
        printf("\n");
        count++;
  }
       return(0);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
debian:~/sam$ ./single_sample

=====================================================
Server Side
=====================================================
Server Sending message 0 size32 :0xff , 0xfd, 0x18,0xff,0xfd,0x23
Server Sending message 1 size17 :0xff , 0xfd, 0x1e
Server Sending message 2 size17 :0xff , 0xfd, 0x1d
Server Sending message 3 size18 :0xff , 0xfd , 0x17
Segmentation fault
```

I had the following doubts:
a)Why is the output showing segmentation fault ?
b)Where to insert Send() method for sending 3 elements of each message viz:

```
Send 1 : 0xff,0xfd,0x18
Send 2 : 0xff,0xfd,0x23
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is going past the end of the `buff1` array which has a length of 4, so it should only be iterating from `count` 0 to 3. I suggest you use a `for` loop instead of the `while` loop and set a condition that checks to ensure it stops when `count` reaches the end of the array length. Otherwise when your loop reaches `count=4` and tries to access `buff1[count].length()` it will cause a seg fault.

```
const int buff_len = 4;
for (int count=0; count < buff_len; count++)
{
    const unsigned char *ptr = (const unsigned char*)buff1[count].c_str();
    printf("Server Sending message %d of size:%d",count,buff1[count].length());
    for(int i = 0 ; i < buff1[count].length(); i++)
    {
        printf("%c",*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: ,if  I do not want to hard code the buffer length,how should I proceed with that ?

Comment: Then you need to populate the vector of strings manually as well. One method would be to use a vector of strings for buff1 as `std::vector<std::string> buff1`, and you can determine the top value in the loop as `for (count=0;count < buff1.length();count++)`